# File access to image files on camera roll (iOS 12.1.4, Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.1)

Tags: swift, xcode, url, camera

I am trying to calculate a file hash for `JPEG` files (e.g. `MD5`) after taking pictures with the builtin camera. I can create a digest over the image data, but that won't be the same as the actual file hash. Looking at the Photo module and its `PHAsset` class, I don't see a way to retrieve the actual file path (URL) which I could then feed to `MD5Digest`. Maybe it's possible to capture the file `URL` right after saving the image to the camera roll, by implementing a completion listener function. Has anyone tried this before?

Updated code with completionHandler, but I still need to find the URL.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var imageHash: UILabel!

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    let orgPic = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(orgPic!, self, #selector(imageSaved(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

}

@objc func imageSaved(_ img: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "\(img.ciImage?.url)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
 }

// the img.ciImage.url is "nil" unfortunately
```

Comment: Hi Iko, it would be great if you could add some code, that would help understand the problem.

Comment: MD5 hash over image data is not the same as a file hash over the JPEG in the camera roll. UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() probably strips some data and then applies JPEG compression before saving. The only way to compute a true file hash would be to discover the file URL and the read it like so "let data = try Data(contentsOf: someFileURL)" then run a hash as in "let digest = data.md5". My question is, can I discover the file URL by providing a completionHandler in the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (would be the 3rd argument)? Thanks much -Iko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your main motto is to compare the MD5s of 2 Image file. So here is what I tried and maybe that would help you

;TLDR - The file saved in Library and the actual file didn't match for me

```
 public func saveImgToLocal(_ img: UIImage,
                           onComplete: @escaping () -> Void) {

    var blockPlaceholder: PHObjectPlaceholder?
    var changeRequest: PHAssetChangeRequest?

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        changeRequest =  PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: img)
        blockPlaceholder = changeRequest?.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    }, completionHandler: { (saved, error) in
        //_saved_ is of type bool, you can use it to check whether image is saved
        //Here we would fetch the asset using our saved placeholder
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        let fetchResult:PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [blockPlaceholder!.localIdentifier], options: fetchOptions)
        if let asset = fetchResult.firstObject {
            //Method to convert asset to Actual image
            self.getAsset(asset: asset)
        }
        onComplete()

    })
}
```

This is how I saved the image to Local

This is how I got the image from Local

```
func getAsset(asset: PHAsset)  {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var resultImage = UIImage()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        resultImage = result!
        let url = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as! NSURL
        //Image created using the file URL.
        let image = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: url.path!)
//I even compared the resultImage instead of the image from the file
        if UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image!) {
            print("Same image")
        }
    })

}
```

So if you just want to get the saved image back, that can be done, but I am not sure whether the image is saved as it is in the Photos Library.
HTH :-)

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Thanks for ending 2 days of misery ;-)

Comment: Thanks :-) Can you accept the answer if it helps? I need points :-p

Answer (score 0):

Although the code Ajinkya Sharma posted worked, I noticed that the performance to save images to the camera roll was significantly slower using creationRequestForAsset compared to UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum. So I opted for a hybrid solution. I saved using the old function, then used the PHAsset framework to fetch the newest image file and retrieve its URL. Problem solved.

```
public func saveImgToLocal(_ img: UIImage) {
    // significantly faster than creationRequestForAsset
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, #selector(imageSaved(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

@objc func imageSaved(_ img: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: fetchOptions)
        if let asset = fetchResult.firstObject
        {
            self.imageHash.text = getAsset(asset: asset)
        }
    }
}

func getAsset(asset: PHAsset) -> String {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var hashString = "" as String
    option.isSynchronous = true
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
        let url = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as! NSURL
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
            hashString = data.md5.rawValue
        }
        catch {
            hashString = "Error computing hash"
        }
    })
    return hashString
}
```